# ASP.NET MVC - How to render a @section in a partal view with parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I use partial views to render the content of the pages.
Normally, I use sections to render specific Scripts and CSS for the content by using @section

My basic url is `{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}`

For urls like `{Controller}/{Action}` ie. `Product/Create`, the sections and the pages render ok.

But when my url is `{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}` ie. `Product/Edit/2`, the CSS and Scripts are absent and I only get a plain HTML page.

My Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

<!-- CSS FILES -->
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- BEGIN RENDER CSS SECTION EXISTING IN PARTIAL -->
    @RenderSection("Style", required: false)
<!-- END RENDER CSS SECTION EXISTING IN PARTIAL -->
    <link href="../assets/global/css/components.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        @Html.Partial("_Header")
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            @Html.Partial("_Sidebar")
        </div>

        <div class="content">
                @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
     <script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- RENDER JAVASCRIPT SECTION EXISTING IN PARTIAL -->
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
<!-- RENDER JAVASCRIPT SECTION EXISTING IN PARTIAL -->

    <script src="../assets/layouts/layout/scripts/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My Partial Views Structure:

```
@model IEnumerable<Backend.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product";
}
@section Style {
SPECIFIC CSS URLS TO THE VIEW
}

HTML CODE

@section Scripts{
SPECIFIC JAVASCRIPT URLS TO THE VIEW
}
```

I'm doubting the additional `{Id}` in the URL is what messes the code because the following:
with {Id}
[image: with {Id}]

When Id is passed as querystring
[image: When Id is passed as querystring]

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: There is not enough information here to even begin.  Try supplying some code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: How are you including your css ? Can you show the code ? Check your browser  network tab for 404 errors. This will give you an idea why it is failing

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I edited my post

Comment: @Shyju I edited my post

Comment: @Mikahel See the answer i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you included the css files is not correct!

You should Use `~/` instead of `../`. Razor will convert `~` to the root path of your app.

This should work.

```
<link href="~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Assuming `assets` folder is in your app root.

With this your link's won't be broken irrespective of what page/url you are on.

You should do the same for including js files also.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. ../ works fine. Notice that even the Layout CSS is not generated, not only the partial's CSS

Comment: You need to do this in the layout as well. ( Wherever you are including any resource)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing your shared layout.  If you have something like this toward the top of the edit cshtml try taking it out.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

If that's not there, maybe you need to specify the layout, you can just replicate whatever is in your create cshtml, for example:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayoutPage.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: I do have my layout. Please see new updates in my question